# Correlation between Poisson and conditionally binomial random variables

Tags: probability

> Let $X \sim \operatorname{Pois}(\lambda)$ and $Y \mid X=x \sim \operatorname{Bin}(x,p)$. Find $\operatorname{Cor}(X,Y)$.

The crucial step in the computation is to find $E(XY)$, which a I did using brute force calculation via the joint PMF and, alternatively, using iterated expecation. I found $E(XY) = pE(X)=p(\lambda^2+\lambda)$ and $\operatorname{Cor}(X,Y) = \sqrt{p}$.

I specifically would like to know if there is an approach using indicator random variables to compute $E(XY)$.

Comment: I've posted an answer that's simpler than the two that are here so far, _provided_ you know a certain standard result about this situation. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Key-tool: *Using indicator functions, one can rewrite every sum on some random set of indices as a sum on a fixed set, possible infinite.*

Let $(U_n)$ denote an i.i.d. sequence of Bernoulli random variables independent of $X$ such that $P(U_n=1)=p$ and $P(U_n=0)=1-p$, then $Y$ can be constructed as $$Y=\sum_{n=1}^XU_n\color{red}{=}\sum_{n=1}^\infty U_n\mathbf 1_{X\geqslant n},$$ The $\color{red}{=}$ sign above is where we used the so-called key-tool stated at the beginning of our post. Now, by independence, $$E(XY)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty E(U_n)E(X\mathbf 1_{X\geqslant n})=p\sum_{n=1}^\infty E(X\mathbf 1_{X\geqslant n}).$$ Note that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mathbf 1_{X\geqslant n}=X,$$ hence $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty E(X\mathbf 1_{X\geqslant n})=E(X^2),$$ and finally, in full generality, $$E(XY)=pE(X^2).$$

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for. I basically surrendered when I realized the random variable $X$ in the limit of the sum.

Answer (score 2):

$X\sim\operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda)$ and $Y\mid X\sim\operatorname{Binomial}(X,p)$ and $Z=X-Y$ then

- $Y\sim\operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda p)$ and
- $Z\sim\operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda(1-p))$ and
- (a crucial point) **$Y, Z$ are independent.**

So $\operatorname{cov}(X,Y) = \operatorname{cov}(Y+Z,Y) = \operatorname{cov}(Y,Y)+\operatorname{cov}(Z,Y) = \operatorname{cov}(Y,Y)+0$.

The rest should be routine.

Comment: Thank you Michael, I know this result, and this was probability the ways intended by the original exercise. However, it is good to see the different approaches work out. That adds to my toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

Given $X= x$, $Y$ is binomial with parameters $x$ and $p$, which means
$E[Y\mid X=x] = px$, i.e. $E[Y\mid X] = p X$.  Thus $E[XY] = E[X E[Y\mid X]] = p E[X^2]$.